# Is there a bug in the review queue?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

It's suddenly showing 178 new items to review, all of which are late answers, all of which seem to be posted *years* ago. I don't think it's a good idea if we start working on them, but if you aren't carefully checking the date you'll probably handle a few, which might bring the questions back to the frontpage for no reason.

Comment: Same thing here.

Answer (score 9):

A suggestion to have the reputation portion of the test that puts a new post into the Late Answer queue [raised from 10 rep to 50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue) has just been implemented. This dumped many old “new” late answers into the queue from users who have 11–50 reputation. This is network-wide — fellow mods from other sites started asking about their review queues spiking, and that post's fresh [status-completed] tag was the answer.

It's by design, not a bug, but somewhat questionably handled. Fortunately, it is a one-time event and once the new backlog is cleared, it will return to normal, just with slightly more items to review per day than before.

On the plus side, this is an excellent opportunity to work towards some [Reviewer badges](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: I reviewed a few, many of which needed little to no action.  The review feature eventually hit a ticker and closed my reviewing tasks for a few hours.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: That the first time you've ever hit a daily review cap? :P Happens all the time over on SO. ;)

Comment: I know the cap's there, it's just that our density of reviews per able body is usually well below some of the other stacks. :-)